# How to convert number with comma to number in Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am testing my Custom Pipe: NoCommaPipe. But when I create a test with input 10,000,000, it returns NaN. How can I create a test with input like: 10,000,000

no-comma.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: 'noComma'
})

export class NoCommaPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(val: number): string {
        let transformedVal: string;
        if(val === undefined || val === null) {
            transformedVal = ""
        } else {
            transformedVal = val.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
        }
        return transformedVal;
    }
}
```

no-comma.pipe.spec.ts:

```
import { NoCommaPipe } from './no-comma.pipe';

fdescribe('NoCommaPipe', () => {

    let noCommaPipe: NoCommaPipe;

    beforeEach(() => {
        noCommaPipe = new NoCommaPipe();
    })

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(noCommaPipe).toBeTruthy();
    })

    it('should return empty string on input is undefined', () => {
        expect(noCommaPipe.transform(undefined)).toEqual('');
    })

    it('should return empty string on input is null', () => {
        expect(noCommaPipe.transform(null)).toEqual('');
    })

    it('should return 10000000 on input equal to 10,000,000', () => {
        expect(noCommaPipe.transform(Number('10,000,000'))).toEqual('10000000');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns NaN because that is what you are supplying as an argument to your method:

```js
console.log(Number('10,000,000'));
```

You can see here that if you don't use `Number()` it works as expected.

```js
function transform(val) {
  let transformedVal;
  if (val === undefined || val === null) {
    transformedVal = ""
  } else {
    transformedVal = val.toString().replace(/,/g, "");
  }
  return transformedVal;
}

console.log(transform(Number('10,000,000')));
console.log(transform('10,000,000'));
```

In response to a comment...

```js
console.log(typeof('10,000,000'));
console.log(typeof(10000000));
console.log(10,000,000);
```

Comment: But I want the Pipe to accept type of number only. Not a string.

Comment: @Roan You can't have a number that has commas. That is type string. That's the way it is.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Roan Please see the update to my post which might make help to clarify :)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in your test

> Number('10,000,000')

It will always return NaN since 10,000,000 isnt recognized as a Number, rather a string.
There's no reason to pass your transform attribute as number in your directive, since your values received will always be strings...

Just change `val: number` to `val: string` or `any` and remove your cast to Number